# Install RPM on Centos

Tags: centos, rpm

I work with Centos 6.4 and RPM. When I install RPM, linux  thows the  error

```
 Installing : XXX 
Error unpacking rpm package XXX
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /lib/libasteriskssl.so;51f7eebf: cpio: Digest mismatch
  Verifying  : XXX
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 9):

Try to run /usr/sbin/prelink -u /lib/libasteriskssl.so after you put it in place it in the %install.