# Compatibility Issue from centos 5.x to 6.x

Tags: linux, rpm, centos6, shared-libraries

I have an rpm compiled in centos 5.x which requires libnetsnmp.so.10 and other shared objects. I want to create an rpm of it which is to be run on centos 6.x but it fails to install as on installation it says :

error: Failed dependencies:
        libnetsnmp.so.10()(64bit) is needed and so on...

But Centos 6.x contains libnetsnmp.so.20
So I created symbolic links of libnetsnmp.so.10 of libnetsnmp.so.20.
But problem is still the same.

So can you please help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Don't create system level symlinks like that. That is never the right answer. Rebuild your RPM on CentOS 6 instead of CentOS 5 and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If recompiling for Centos 6 isn't an option, you can try two things, first, install the correct libnetsnmp in the Centos 6 server. If that's not an option, you can add the following to your RPM spec file:

```
Autoreq: no
```

This will cause it not to scan your binary for dependencies (such as dynamically linked libraries), and automatically build that into the RPM.

Of course, if that version of libnetsnmp is ACTUALLY required, your just hosing yourself down the road, but likely newer versions will work just fine.

Comment: If I make links for libnetsnmp.so.10 of libnetsnmp.so.20 the binary runs fine if I just copy the binary.

But I need to install the rpm.
Is there any way to do that?

Or is there a way to exclude only this dependency in the spec file of rpm?

Comment: Disabling automatic requirements is only going to help with the RPM dependency that prevents installation. It will not, by itself, make the binary work (the symlinks, or something equally as terrible of an idea, would also be necessary).

Comment: @Etan his question was how to get the RPM to install. He can either recreate the RPM without dependencies, or install with --nodep.

Comment: @khopdi You can either follow my answer or install the RPM with --nodeps. There's no other way to do it. Try "man rpm" for installation and dependency options.

Comment: I am able to resolve dependencies. But I am getting cpio: digest mismatch error.

How to resolve that?

Comment: @khopdi I've not seen that error before, but it is talked about here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17948184/3652920

Comment: @CDahn: Where do we use this %install option as given in link provided by you?

Comment: Digest mismatch in rpm cpio is usually because a binary library that has been prelinked ended up in the *.rpm. make sure binary libraries are not prelinked if including directly in an rpm package.